# Qualtrics: Linking directly to a block/ 'block' in a modal

Tags: css, qualtrics

After feedback on piloting a survey, I've been asked to have a clickable link (in the header of the survey) that takes respondents to an information sheet where they also have the option to Opt Out of the survey.

Therefore, is it possible to either link to a specific block and then allow participants to return to where they were in the survey

OR

Is it possible to have a button open a modal containing the information and option opt out question.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean opt-out of the Qualtrics panel/mailing list?

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear; I mean opt-out of the survey. So, for example, by checking a text box their responses will be removed immediately when data is exported later

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do a survey non-sequentially is using a Table of Contents with some custom JavaScript, but that wouldn't work for what you are trying to do.

You can have a link to a JavaScript that would set an opt-out embedded variable. Then you can check the embedded variable to screen-out opt-out responses at any end-of-survey point. You'd also have to set your survey options to delete in-progress responses after 1 week so no opt-outs slip into your data.